# How to pass the model ID across the pages in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to pass the Model.Game ID from Details page to another view page which is Cart.
The way I do is inserting the `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Game.ID)` in the app-route-id. Is that appropriate to do so?

**Details.cshtml**

```
@page "{id:int}"
@model GameSanctuary.Pages.Games.DetailsModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Game</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Game.G_Description)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Game.G_Description)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Game.G_Genre)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Game.G_Genre)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Game.G_Price)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Game.G_Price)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-page="./Index">Back to List</a>
    <a asp-page="./Cart" asp-page-handler="buynow" class="btn" asp-route-id="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Game.ID)">Add to Cart</a>
</div>
```

**Cart.cshtml.cs**

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetBuyNow(int id)
        {
            cart = SessionHelper.GetObjectFromJson<List<Item>>(HttpContext.Session, "cart");
            if (cart == null)
            {
                cart = new List<Item>();
                cart.Add(new Item
                {
                    Game = await _context.Game.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id)
                });
                SessionHelper.SetObjectAsJson(HttpContext.Session, "cart", cart);
            }
            return RedirectToPage("Cart");
        }
```

The id value that I retrieved in `OnGetBuyNow` is 0 but the expected value should be 1 based on the model.Game.ID in `Details.cshtml`. Is that something missing in between?

Answer (score 0):

no, it's not appropriate.

`Html.DisplayFor()` renders the display template which matches whatever type you use it on. That's not what you want. What you want is a simple number surely which can be injected directly like this:

```
asp-route-id="@Model.Game.ID"
```

I would start there and see if that gives you what you want

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what i want